# Expo's Android app not responding properly to code changes and shaking

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I've started developing a react-native app using Expo and running it in my Android phone. Things worked OK at first but then suddenly:

- Every time I introduced a syntax error on my code, my phone would not display the compiling errors (they used to appear as white text on a red background) but instead it would show an uninformative error screen with a blue background.
- My phone stopped responding to the shake gesture in order to access the dev menu. (I wonder who thought that shaking was a good idea as opposed to a more conventional menu...)
- Live recompiling stopped working.
- Even when refreshing manually, changes to my code sometimes won't be applied. It looks like the expo app is working with an old, cached version of my code.

Expo is indeed running in production mode. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned your project is running in production mode you must change it to development mode, you can do this by clicking the toggle button on `expo-cli`'s interface.

[image: expo-cli UI]

Alternatively if you're using Expo CLI just press `p` while your project is running to toggle between modes.

You can read more about Dev/production modes [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/development-mode/).

Comment: Yes, this was already set to production mode and yet the problems persist.

Comment: In the picture the toggle is deactivated, meaning it's dev mode. Is that the same way your toggle is presenting itself or is it purple?

Comment: OK, the first three problems were solved when setting both things to dev mode. Thanks! However, it is still working with an old version of my code (I had a typo in a module name I was importing, which I already fixed, and my app is still crashing because of a 'module not found error')

Comment: Sometimes helps to stop Metro Builder and then restart it

Comment: Try to restart both your project and `expo-cli`.